# How to loop through scattered selection of cells using an array

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, excel

I have a spreadsheet with scattered cells that I want to outline in a thick border.  I've put the cells in an array.  Some are individual cells and some are contiguous groupings.  Because the code for adding these borders is lengthy, I want to loop through the cells that will have borders.

The line where I am trying to select the cell is using syntax I made up and it clearly doesn't work.  Is there any syntax that would work, or am I approaching the problem the wrong way?

---

```
arrCellBorders = Array("A2", "A3", "A6", "B5", "G1", "E7:E10", "E19:E22", "E33:E36", "I7:I10", "I19:I22", "I33:I36", "K7:K10", "K19:K21", "K33", "O7:O10", "O19:O21", "O33", "Q7", "Q9:Q10", "U7", "U9:U10")

For iCounter = 0 To 20

    Range("arrCellBorders(iCounter)").Select
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With

Next iCounter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub qwerty()
    arrCellBorders = Array("A2", "A3", "A6", "B5", "G1", "E7:E10", "E19:E22", "E33:E36", "I7:I10", "I19:I22", "I33:I36", "K7:K10", "K19:K21", "K33", "O7:O10", "O19:O21", "O33", "Q7", "Q9:Q10", "U7", "U9:U10")
    For i = 0 To 20
        Range(arrCellBorders(i)).Select
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, just:

```
arrCellBorders = Array("A2", "A3", "A6", "B5", "G1", "E7:E10", "E19:E22", "E33:E36", _
                        "I7:I10", "I19:I22", "I33:I36", "K7:K10", "K19:K21", "K33", "O7:O10", _
                        "O19:O21", "O33", "Q7", "Q9:Q10", "U7", "U9:U10")

For iCounter = LBound(arrCellBorders) To UBound(arrCellBorders)
    Range(arrCellBorders(iCounter)).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, ColorIndex:=0, Weight:=xlMedium
Next iCounter
```